# Hibernate - Mixed entity/component inheritance mapping

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, orm

Let's assume I have following class hierarchy:

```
interface Client:
    String name
    String country

class RegisteredClient implements Client:
    String assignedId

class UnregisteredClient implements Client

class ClientRisk:
    Client client
    int riskLevel
```

The idea is that `ClientRisk` can have either link to a registered client with an id (which is custom and comes from elsewhere), or some custom client (not registered). Now the following DB structure exists:

```
REGISTERED_CLIENT(ASSIGNED_ID, NAME, COUNTRY)
CLIENT_RISK(REG_CLIENT_ID, UNREG_NAME, UNREG_COUNTRY, RISK_LEVEL)
```

I mapped this entities with Hibernate such as that there's two hidden fields in `ClientRisk`, one referencing `RegisteredClient` and the other one -- `UnregisteredClient` which is mapped as a component. And I added a property `client` to it which differentiates between these two fields at run-time.

This is kind of ugly solution, and it doesn't scale (I can't just write `client.name` in criteria or HQL, for example). On the other hand, I don't want to put unregistered clients into another table since it's, well, custom and is not shared anyhow. Neither I want to map `UnregisteredClient` as an entity based on `CLIENT_RISK` table, this would cause unnecessary joins (`CLIENT_RISK JOIN CLIENT_RISK`).

My question is, what is the best way to handle such kind of situation in Hibernate?